# Fetch multiple images from SharePoint library and display images in SPFX webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react, pnpjs, react-webpart

SharePoint Library -- Multiple image and HexID field

I am able to display one image by giving full URL of images but i have to filter the images based on HexID, But I am not sure how to apply filter, Please help me how to filter and get the image and bind into web-part,

Below Code.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IFlowDiagramProps> {
var str="";
var str1='<img src="https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz/DiagramLib/ManageProjectPortfolio.png" useMap='+usemaps+'>'+str+'</img>';
return (
              <div className={styles.pivotbackgroud} >
                <div className={styles.processheading}>Process Overview</div>
                <Pivot aria-label="Large Link Size Pivot Example" linkSize={PivotLinkSize.normal}>
                  <PivotItem headerText="Flow">            
                    <div id="image_map" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: str1}}>  //Here i can bind one image
                    </div>                     
                  </PivotItem>

                  <PivotItem headerText="Description">
                  </PivotItem>
                </Pivot>
              </div>
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this.

Put the logic to get the images in a method:

```
  private getTheImages() {
    let url = "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('DiagramLib')/items"+
      "?$select=FileLeafRef"+
      "&$filter=HexID eq '27DB2B7156297051'";
    let images = [];
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((result:SPHttpClientResponse) => {
          result.json().then((jsonresult) => {
              jsonresult.value.forEach(image => {
                images.push(<img src={`https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz/DiagramLib/${image.FileLeafRef}`} />);
              });
      }).then(()=> { 
        this.setState({ fetchedimages: images });
    });
  });
}
```

Add the constructor to your class:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fetchedimages: []
    };
    this.getTheImages();
  }
```

( Depending on your class constructor you might have to add `fetchedimages` to the state interface, but I am guessing you have it standard with `{} / any` )

Now, update your render code:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IFlowDiagramProps> {
  return (
              <div className={styles.pivotbackgroud} >
                <div className={styles.processheading}>Process Overview</div>
                <Pivot aria-label="Large Link Size Pivot Example" linkSize={PivotLinkSize.normal}>
                  <PivotItem headerText="Flow">            
                    <div id="image_map">
                      { this.state.fetchedImages }
                    </div>                     
                  </PivotItem>

                  <PivotItem headerText="Description">
                  </PivotItem>
                </Pivot>
              </div>
            );
}
```

I would recommend reading up on React and how this is all tied together, in this example I have omitted the image map portion - you probably need some logic to tie that in as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Rune

Its really great help for me.. its working perfectly,

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help others facing the same issue.

Comment: I am new here , how to mark acceptable, I am not able to see any button here

Comment: To the left of the answers, underneath the voting arrows, there should be a checkmark visible that you can press.